# Textfield to URL (PHP)

Tags: php

```
//Search button for SeekingAlpha
echo '<div id="searchAlpha">';
echo '<FORM NAME="form1" ACTION="http://www.seekingalpha.com/symbol/" METHOD="POST">';
echo '<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="symbol" placeholder="Search by symbol, author, keyboard..." / VALUE="<?php echo $symbol;?> "> <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit">';echo '</FORM>';  echo '</div>';  //end SeekingAlpha
```

My question is - How do I exactly get the textfield variable to the URL?
For instance - when a user type a stock symbol into the textfield, it would type out as http://www.seekingalpha.com/symbol/$symbol where $symbol is the input from textfield

Thanks!

Comment: use get, not post

Comment: You already are echoing so don't do `<?php echo $symbol;?>`.

Comment: I tried GET and I failed to make it work. Can you please elaborate? and I figured on echoing @chris85 i wasnt sure.